# select not null values from table Mysql

Tags: mysql

guys i have problems with select not null values from my table

```
$tabelka = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from ".$server_db.".paczka_przedmiot where cos = ".$losuj['test1']." 
or cos = ".$losuj['test2']."
or cos = ".$losuj['test3']."
or cos = ".$losuj['test4']."
or cos = ".$losuj['test5']."
or cos = ".$losuj['test6']." order by rand() limit 1"));
$szansa = rand(1,100000);
```

i arleady try with add and (cos IS NOT NULL)
but doesnt work here is my full code

```
$tabelka = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from ".$server_db.".paczka_przedmiot where cos = ".$losuj['test1']." 
or cos = ".$losuj['test2']."
or cos = ".$losuj['test3']."
or cos = ".$losuj['test4']."
or cos = ".$losuj['test5']."
or cos = ".$losuj['test6']."  and (cos IS NOT NULL) order by rand() limit 1"));
$szansa = rand(1,100000);
```

Comment: did you try without fast brackets before cos IS NOT NULL

Comment: @rowmoin ofcourse

Comment: What error showing when you run this query

Comment: @rowmoin Nothing but still select from tables field with a null value

Comment: You can try this SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE NOT (YourColumn <=> NULL);

Comment: If your problem solved then accepted my solution according to stavkoverflow rules

Comment: @rowmoin i don't know how i can use you solution because i have here rand and or , or ,or

Comment: Both of your queries should **not** return anay row where `cos` is NULL. BTW: You can use `WHERE cos IN(.., .., ..)` instead of multiple OR conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alternative query but its not a standard:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE NOT (YourColumn <=> NULL);
```

You also should use uppercase "AND"

You can try this also:

```
mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from ".$server_db.".paczka_przedmiot where cos IS NOT NULL AND (cos = ".$losuj['test1']. " 
OR cos = ".$losuj['test2']. "
OR cos = ".$losuj['test3']. "
OR cos = ".$losuj['test4']. "
OR cos = ".$losuj['test5']. "
OR cos = ".$losuj['test6']. ") ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1"));
```

Comment: don't return any values

Comment: Both of your queries should not return anay row where cos is NULL. Are you sure do you have a value for this query?

Comment: $losuj['test2'] = 2 $losuj['test1'] = 1 $losuj['test3'] = 3 $losuj['test4'] = 4 $losuj['test5'] = null $losuj['test6'] null

Comment: what do you want to mean by this? do you have a value in your table where cos=2 or cos=1?

Comment: Could you please try again mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from ".$server_db.".paczka_przedmiot where cos IS NOT NULL AND (cos = ".$losuj['test1']. " 
OR cos = ".$losuj['test2']. "
OR cos = ".$losuj['test3']. "
OR cos = ".$losuj['test4']. "
OR cos = ".$losuj['test5']. "
OR cos = ".$losuj['test6']. ") ORDER BY rainnd() LIMIT 1")); I have some changed  in query

Comment: dont work. i can check before use rand $losuj['test4'] value? if not null then use it

Comment: What data type you used for soc field?

Comment: did you use default NULL or you passing string null value this field?

Comment: if you passing null value as a string then you should check bye quotation when you condition check for every null value like OR cos ="$losuj['test5']"

Comment: int NULL (i can use not null)

Comment: Hay I think you are something missing. Your query is perfect but your logic has some problem did you send me that you have a data in your table for  test6 = null or test5 = null  if is it then when your query has value because you already told your query that if( IS NOT NULL AND  test6 = null or test5 = null)  then how to expect that showing result

Comment: you add some data in your table for soc 1,2,3

Comment: and also you should space for after every OR condition

Comment: here is problem too on rand.how i can select only when rand is 100%?

Comment: yup, can you little explain how i can use rand? because i want like 1 = chance 5% 2 = chance 90% 3 = chance 100% 4 = chance 100% now how i can rand it? and get only one value ?

Comment: you can raise an another question. If you using any programming language then it can easily handle you just get the number of row return and you will decide what % you want to show.

Comment: it will be like that : SELECT 0 INTO @x;

SELECT itemID, COUNT(*) as ordercount, (@x:=@x+1) as rownumber (case when (rownumber = 2 ) 
 THEN
      90%
 ELSE
      0  FROM orders GROUP BY itemID ORDER BY ordercount DESC;

Comment: But am not sure 100%. It will be better you raise another question then some one can help you.

Comment: i see like on games, you have 100% chance 1,2,3,4,5,6 items but only one items you get and for rare items you have just 5% and when rare items you draw then you get rare items without normal items with chance 100% for me is to hard. i'm weak mathemathic.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that the problem is in the parenthesis. This correction should work (pay attention to the parenthesis):

```
$tabelka = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from ".$server_db.".paczka_przedmiot where (cos = ".$losuj['test1']." 
or cos = ".$losuj['test2']."
or cos = ".$losuj['test3']."
or cos = ".$losuj['test4']."
or cos = ".$losuj['test5']."
or cos = ".$losuj['test6']." ) and (cos IS NOT NULL) order by rand() limit 1"));
$szansa = rand(1,100000);
```